# Clonezilla virtualbox setup

Tags: virtualbox, clone, clonezilla

I've set up a virtual Ubuntu desktop in virtualbox, and I was wondering how I can use Clonezilla (or software like it) to clone it as an iso to install onto multiple desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Boot you virtual server with clonezilla and create .img.
With colonezilla you can transfer .img directly to you host via ssh.
Only what can make problem is specific drivers on desktop when restore .img file.